# Mantaflow not going hires

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I'm using the blender 2.81 mantaflow beta build and, I've set up a smoke scene and, as I understand it, the "Noise" setting is the equivalent of the "High Resolution" setting before so, when I check noise and bake the sim, the fire and smoke disappears and then when I uncheck it, it reappears. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Is mantaflow included with 2.80? are you using a plugin, or does blender 2.81 come included with mantaflow, finally?

Comment: You have to go to blender.org>download blender 2.80>get blender experimental(bottom of page)>then click on the "experimental branches" link below the blue "new features and changes" button.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry guys, I figured out the answer but wanted to post this to help others. You need to bake the noise as well before you can see the result.